# Are there specific classifiers or ways to tune commonly used classifiers such that they minimize the number of false positives?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset with which I want to train a binary classifier. I have been experimenting with various approaches including SVM, NN, Logistic Regression and in each case have used the classifier to calculate a probability of a positive result. It is important to me to minimize the number of false positives as much as possible. Are there any classifiers that are designed in such a way as to minimize false positives or are there ways of adapting any of the most common classifiers such that they minimize false positives? Approximately 1/2 of the samples in the training set have a positive dependent variable. Likewise, a typical set of samples for which I want to make predictions will also have an approx. even split between dependent variables with a value of 0 or 1.

Perhaps another way of saying what I would like to achieve … I would be happy to sacrifice accuracy for lower probability positive predictions if I could achieve higher accuracy for the higher probability positive predictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make false positives = 0 by the very simple method of always saying "negative" and then you don't even need to do any analysis.

That's probably not what you want - although it does minimize them.

Instead, most classifiers have some sort of cost function that you can adjust. Or, if you make an ROC curve, you can pick a point for yourself.

Comment: It had occurred to me that adjusting the cost function might be the way to proceed. I will explore this option. In the meantime, if anyone has an example of a cost function designed to reduce false positives, I would appreciate it if they would post the logic as an example. If/when I design one that works, I will post it here.